# Set grid page number

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I use `Ext.grid.Panel` with proxy store and `pagingtoolbar`. How can I set page number from code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `store.loadPage(x)` to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You may also use this if you want to pass more params:

```
store.load({
    params: {
        page: 2,
        limit: 20,
        myParam: 10
    }
});
```

Comment: This reloads page from server but doesn't set page numner in `pagingtoolbar`

Comment: This works, but add store.currentPage = 1; first to fix the paging toolbar.